# .focus() event is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

when my php page loads some jQuery should set focus to my input textbox but it does not

I have tried css selectors like `input[tabindex=1]` and `#31` but to no avail...

here is the jQuery (version 1.7.1)

```
$(function() {
$('input[tabindex=1]').focus(); // also tried   $('#31').focus(); 
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<input tabindex='1' type='text' class='tablefilter' id='31' style='width:80px;border:inset 2px grey;background-color:white;font-size:12px;border-radius:0px;-moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px;'/>
```

any clues as to why this isn't working?

Comment: What browser? Sometimes doing the focus in a `setTimeout()` (with a very short timer) helps.

Comment: Works for me; http://jsfiddle.net/DUxkH/

Comment: using IE9 let me test with ff and chrome, i have those installed too

Comment: nope doesn't work in FF either (on a side note FF is painfilly slow to open that's why I use IE, it opens very quickly, no addons in FF so it shouldn't be slowed by anything like that), and Chrome also fails

Comment: fyi "31" is no valid `id`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using a numeric ID for a reason to filter (hide) table rows based on text typed into the text field in question, it works now though

Comment: and EWW html4?? I am coding with HTML 5 standards, they're a little looser

Answer (score 0):

check this out, i just tried your code, it works. which version of jquery are you using? which browser are you using, try open console to see, if there is an exception.

here is the demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jaiwo99/PCm9s/)

Comment: jquery-1.7.1.js
ie9

thats neat but since my code is exactly the same it doesn't help a lot, but its somewhat comforting to know it works for you :)